# How to clean up dev/sda1 as it's full

Tags: disk-usage, memory-usage

I've been doing jmeter tests and have had a few `OutOfMemoryExceptions`, so I've bumped up the heap memory in JMeter. But now it seems I can't run anymore tests as it says I'm using 94.9% of 14Gb.

When I use `df -h` it says `dev/sda1` is full

I was wondering if anyone can help me? I think it has to do with the JVM from the jmeter

Comment: Did you see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot?

Answer (score 19):

Start by tracking down where the excess usage is being stored.  If you have no idea, start from the mountpoint for /dev/sda1:

```
mount | grep sda1
```

Use the du command.  If /dev/sda1 is mounted on /  ("root"):

```
du --max-depth=1 --human-readable / | sort --human-numeric-sort
```

This will list the first level of directories contained in the specified path, in order from smallest to largest. You can increase the depth past 1 to get details of the subdirectories, or change the path to specify a single directory.  You can also use the short flags.

For instance, if your username is ubuntu and you want to inspect your home directory:

```
du -d1 -h /home/ubuntu | sort -h
```

Comment: The correct answer is in @Takkat's comment above: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot

Comment: Takkat's comment refers to having a separate boot partition that gets full, which was not the case here. My answer is a general approach to determine where space is consumed on any full partition.

Answer (score 2):

My culprit is almost always docker (can get bloated when I test multiple applications). If anyone else also experiences similar problems, a deep cleaning with `docker system prune -a` could help.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it could be coming from Jenkins or Docker. To solve that, you should [**clean Jenkings logs  and set it's size**](https://puvox.software/blog/solution-clean-full-disk-space-by-dev-vda1/).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, running the command

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

solved the problem.